# Java generic method adding different objects into different arraylists

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

i want to make method that depending on class i pass as a parameter, pushes object of a class it into a specific arraylist:

```
public class Main {
    private ArrayList<SomeClass1> sc1;
    private ArrayList<SomeClass2> sc2;

    public Main()
    {
        sc1 = new ArrayList<SomeClass1>();
        sc2 = new ArrayList<SomeClass2>();
    }

    public <T> void add(Class<T> type)
    {
            //code for method that depending on type pushes objects into either sc1 or sc2
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        SomeClass1 some1 = new SomeClass1();
        SomeClass2 some2 = new SomeClass2();

        m.add(some1); //here i want some1 to be stored in sc1
        m.add(some2); // here i want some2 to be stored in sc2
    }
}
```

i would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want `add()` to do. Could you fill in `main()` with some calls to it and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Generics aren't magic, you just need if statements and check for the type within that if statement in your add class.

Also your method signature is conflicting, are you returning something or are you returning void, I'll assume void. You also don't really need a constructor, just use your main method to initialize your two arraylists

```
public void add(Class<T> type) {
    if(type instanceOf SomeClass1) {
        // do work here
    } else if (type instanceOf SomeClass2) {
        // do other work here
    }
 }
```